# How to run this "batch" file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I am trying to run a script, which I was told was a batch script; here's the first block, for syntactical reference...

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\TakeOwnership]
@="Take Ownership"
"HasLUAShield"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"Position"="middle"
...
```

However, saving the contents into a `.bat` container and running through elevated `cmd` or `ps` doesn't seem to work, nor does it seem to be a `.reg` file.  How should this be run?

Comment: Definitely not a batch file. That looks like a reg file. If you export any reg file - you should notice similar pattern. You should be able to export (any reg file) and follow the same format, and then re-import it. Or just follow the exact line by line, and find those registry and add them manually (if it is from an untrusted source, or to be 100% sure you know what it is doing).

Comment: It a RegFile without the first line. `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00` followed by a blank line. BTW it does nothing as their is no command specified to run. Sommething like `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Take Ownership\Shell\command` `@="takeown /a \"%1\""`

Comment: `@="takeown /a /f \"%1\""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the code below and save as `file.bat` or `file.cmd`
2. Add this line as command for bat add key/value itself in register

- **`;@(cls & %__APPDIR__%reg.exe import "%~f0" 2>nul >nul & goto :EOF)`**

3. Run as administrator

```py
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 

;@(cls & %__APPDIR__%reg.exe import "%~f0" 2>nul >nul & goto :EOF)

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\TakeOwnership]
@="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\"
"HasLUAShield"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"Position"="middle"
```

- Or maybe you can use the code described on this blog **[easily take ownership and grant full control-permission with win ownership](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/easily-take-ownership-and-grant-full-control-permission-with-winownership/)** from **[raymond.cc/blog](https://www.raymond.cc/blog)**: ...

```py
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 

;@(cls & %__APPDIR__%reg.exe import "%~f0" 2>nul >nul & goto :EOF)

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\runas]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\runas]
@="Take Ownership"
"HasLUAShield"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"Position"="middle"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F /c /l"
"IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F /c /l"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
@="Take Ownership"
"HasLUAShield"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"Position"="middle"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" /r /d y && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F /t /c /l /q"
"IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" /r /d y && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F /t /c /l /q"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dllfile\shell\runas]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dllfile\shell\runas]
@="Take Ownership"
"HasLUAShield"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"Position"="middle"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dllfile\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F /c /l"
"IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F /c /l"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\runas]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\runas]
@="Take Ownership"
"HasLUAShield"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"Position"="middle"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" /r /d y && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F /t /c /l /q"
"IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" /r /d y && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F /t /c /l /q"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runas]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runas]
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runas\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"
"IsolatedCommand"="\"%1\" %*"
```