# How to convert multiple .reg files for use in a single .bat script?

Tags: batch-file, windows-registry, conversion

I have three `.reg` files and need to use them in one `.bat` script:

```reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLUA"=dword:00000001
```

---

```reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Originally created at howtogeek.com

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLUA"=dword:00000000
```

---

```reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International]
"Locale"="00000809"
"LocaleName"="en-GB"
"s1159"="AM"
"s2359"="PM"
"sCountry"="United Kingdom"
"sCurrency"="£"
"sDate"="/"
"sDecimal"="."
"sGrouping"="3;0"
"sLanguage"="ENG"
"sList"=","
"sLongDate"="d MMMM yyyy"
"sMonDecimalSep"="."
"sMonGrouping"="3;0"
"sMonThousandSep"=","
"sNativeDigits"="0123456789"
"sNegativeSign"="-"
"sPositiveSign"=""
"sShortDate"="dd/MM/yyyy"
"sThousand"=","
"sTime"=":"
"sTimeFormat"="HH:mm:ss"
"sShortTime"="HH:mm"
"sYearMonth"="MMMM yyyy"
"iCalendarType"="1"
"iCountry"="44"
"iCurrDigits"="2"
"iCurrency"="0"
"iDate"="1"
"iDigits"="2"
"NumShape"="1"
"iFirstDayOfWeek"="0"
"iFirstWeekOfYear"="0"
"iLZero"="1"
"iMeasure"="0"
"iNegCurr"="1"
"iNegNumber"="1"
"iPaperSize"="9"
"iTime"="1"
"iTimePrefix"="0"
"iTLZero"="1"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\Geo]
"Nation"="244"
```

Comment: Please specify what you wish to accomplish. If it's only ensuring that all three files are applied to the Registry, I recommend you look at the [`REG` command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg) at Microsoft Docs or at [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html). You can always put multiple `REG` commands into your batch file...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mash everything into a single registry file:

```reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLUA"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLUA"=dword:00000000
    
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International] 
"Locale"="00000809"
"LocaleName"="en-GB"
"s1159"="AM"
"s2359"="PM"
"sCountry"="United Kingdom"
"sCurrency"="£"
"sDate"="/"
"sDecimal"="."
"sGrouping"="3;0"
"sLanguage"="ENG"
"sList"=","
"sLongDate"="d MMMM yyyy"
"sMonDecimalSep"="."
"sMonGrouping"="3;0"
"sMonThousandSep"=","
"sNativeDigits"="0123456789"
"sNegativeSign"="-"
"sPositiveSign"=""
"sShortDate"="dd/MM/yyyy"
"sThousand"=","
"sTime"=":"
"sTimeFormat"="HH:mm:ss"
"sShortTime"="HH:mm"
"sYearMonth"="MMMM yyyy"
"iCalendarType"="1"
"iCountry"="44"
"iCurrDigits"="2"
"iCurrency"="0"
"iDate"="1"
"iDigits"="2"
"NumShape"="1"
"iFirstDayOfWeek"="0"
"iFirstWeekOfYear"="0"
"iLZero"="1"
"iMeasure"="0"
"iNegCurr"="1"
"iNegNumber"="1"
"iPaperSize"="9"
"iTime"="1"
"iTimePrefix"="0"
"iTLZero"="1"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\Geo]
"Nation"="244"
```

Comment: 2. Remove the double "Windows REGEDIT" headers. 3. Ponder the usefulness of setting `EnableLUA` to 1 and then back to 0 again...

Comment: @user1686  I just do what the OP wants and try not to think about why so hard.

Comment: THANKS ;) I Remove the double "Windows REGEDIT" THANKS ;) THANKS ;)

Answer (score 6):

You could use the free
[Reg Converter](https://www.sordum.org/files/downloads.php?reg-converter)
to convert any `.reg` file to
[reg commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg)
that you may put in a `.bat` file,

For example, here how it converts the third and longest of your files,
adding a test for administrator permissions (required for `reg` commands).

You may do the same for the other two smaller files and add their
`reg` commands to this file:

```bat
@Echo Off
Title Reg Converter v1.2 & Color 1A
cd %systemroot%\system32
call :IsAdmin

Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "Locale" /t REG_SZ /d "00000809" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "LocaleName" /t REG_SZ /d "en-GB" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "s1159" /t REG_SZ /d "AM" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "s2359" /t REG_SZ /d "PM" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sCountry" /t REG_SZ /d "United Kingdom" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sCurrency" /t REG_SZ /d "£" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sDate" /t REG_SZ /d "/" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sDecimal" /t REG_SZ /d "." /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sGrouping" /t REG_SZ /d "3;0" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sLanguage" /t REG_SZ /d "ENG" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sList" /t REG_SZ /d "," /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sLongDate" /t REG_SZ /d "d MMMM yyyy" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sMonDecimalSep" /t REG_SZ /d "." /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sMonGrouping" /t REG_SZ /d "3;0" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sMonThousandSep" /t REG_SZ /d "," /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sNativeDigits" /t REG_SZ /d "0123456789" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sNegativeSign" /t REG_SZ /d "-" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sPositiveSign" /t REG_SZ /d "" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sShortDate" /t REG_SZ /d "dd/MM/yyyy" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sThousand" /t REG_SZ /d "," /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sTime" /t REG_SZ /d ":" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sTimeFormat" /t REG_SZ /d "HH:mm:ss" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sShortTime" /t REG_SZ /d "HH:mm" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "sYearMonth" /t REG_SZ /d "MMMM yyyy" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "iCalendarType" /t REG_SZ /d "1" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "iCountry" /t REG_SZ /d "44" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "iCurrDigits" /t REG_SZ /d "2" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "iCurrency" /t REG_SZ /d "0" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "iDate" /t REG_SZ /d "1" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "iDigits" /t REG_SZ /d "2" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "NumShape" /t REG_SZ /d "1" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "iFirstDayOfWeek" /t REG_SZ /d "0" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "iFirstWeekOfYear" /t REG_SZ /d "0" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "iLZero" /t REG_SZ /d "1" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "iMeasure" /t REG_SZ /d "0" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "iNegCurr" /t REG_SZ /d "1" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "iNegNumber" /t REG_SZ /d "1" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "iPaperSize" /t REG_SZ /d "9" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "iTime" /t REG_SZ /d "1" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "iTimePrefix" /t REG_SZ /d "0" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "iTLZero" /t REG_SZ /d "1" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\International\Geo" /v "Nation" /t REG_SZ /d "244" /f
Exit

:IsAdmin
Reg.exe query "HKU\S-1-5-19\Environment"
If Not %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
  Cls & Echo You must have administrator rights to continue ... 
  Pause & Exit
)
Cls
goto:eof
```

Comment: That reg converter looks interesting. Do you have a webpage of them, rather than a direct link?

Comment: I downloaded it from [this page](https://windowsreport.com/reg-to-bat-converter/).

Comment: Thanks. I was curious if it had support for reg to powershell, seems that is not the case. :) And yes, I can just copy that in a powershell script anyway, but prefer to use powershell's own reg commands.

Comment: I downloaded it from this page : https://www.sordum.org/8478/reg-converter-v1-2/

Answer (score 5):

For one or more Registry entries in a unified file, try this [hybrid](https://superuser.com/a/1558714/969781) `file.cmd` + `file.reg`:

- Save as `file.bat`/`file.cmd` and run as Admin:

  ```reg
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  ;@(cls & %__APPDIR__%reg.exe import "%~f0" >nul 2>nul & goto :EOF)

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
  "EnableLUA"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International]
  "Locale"="00000809"
  "LocaleName"="en-GB"
  "s1159"="AM"
  "s2359"="PM"
  "sCountry"="United Kingdom"
  "sCurrency"="£"
  "sDate"="/"
  "sDecimal"="."
  "sGrouping"="3;0"
  "sLanguage"="ENG"
  "sList"=","
  "sLongDate"="d MMMM yyyy"
  "sMonDecimalSep"="."
  "sMonGrouping"="3;0"
  "sMonThousandSep"=","
  "sNativeDigits"="0123456789"
  "sNegativeSign"="-"
  "sPositiveSign"=""
  "sShortDate"="dd/MM/yyyy"
  "sThousand"=","
  "sTime"=":"
  "sTimeFormat"="HH:mm:ss"
  "sShortTime"="HH:mm"
  "sYearMonth"="MMMM yyyy"
  "iCalendarType"="1"
  "iCountry"="44"
  "iCurrDigits"="2"
  "iCurrency"="0"
  "iDate"="1"
  "iDigits"="2"
  "NumShape"="1"
  "iFirstDayOfWeek"="0"
  "iFirstWeekOfYear"="0"
  "iLZero"="1"
  "iMeasure"="0"
  "iNegCurr"="1"
  "iNegNumber"="1"
  "iPaperSize"="9"
  "iTime"="1"
  "iTimePrefix"="0"
  "iTLZero"="1"

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\Geo]
  "Nation"="244"
  ```

**Obs. 1.** only one value will be used; when adding one, the other value will overwrite the first, so use one or the other in the same reg, not both:

```reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLUA"=dword:00000001

; // use one or the other not both  // ;

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLUA"=dword:00000000
```

---

**Obs.: 2.** You can also save it as `file.reg`, the line where it starts with `;` will be treated as a comment, to import replace `%__APPDIR__%reg.exe import "%~f0"` with `%__APPDIR__%reg.exe import "file.reg"`

Comment: thanks man .. i will remove one of that @iTwasnTme

Comment: thanks @JW0914 u help me aloot :)